# Iniciar uma virtualenv com arquivo .bat

Tags: python, django, bash, virtualenv

Tenho o seguinte .bat

```
cd C:\Users\SERVIDOR-ARQUIVOS\Documents\workspace\email\.venv\Scripts
activate.bat
cd C:\Users\SERVIDOR-ARQUIVOS\Documents\workspace\email\src
python manage.py (comando personalizado)
```

Ele vai até a pasta mas fecha quando executa o `activate.bat`, queria colocar esse script para rodar uma vez por dia.

Se alguém souber como me ajudar fico agradecido

Comment: não entendi o problema, ele não executa o segundo .bat ou executa e este bat que faz fechar? qual o conteúdo do `activate.bat`?

Comment: O prompt fecha na segunda linha, quando tenta executar o 'activate.bat'. Se eu abrir um prompt normalmente e for até esse caminho e executar ele funciona normal

Comment: então você terá de executar utilizando o `call nome.bat`, para que o processo não seja interrompido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para executar um outro .bat dentro do seu arquivo, você precisa chamar ele utilizando

`call activate.bat`

supondo que estejam na mesma pasta

se não usar call ele interrompe o processo atual para executar o novo.

Comment: Acabei de testar e funcionou. Obrigado meu amigo !